# enumitem: How to change label on enumerate* when inline option is enabled?

Tags: lists, formatting, enumitem, starred-version

I'm using an inline enumerate list in my document, and I want to make that label slightly different (prepend with a `(`) compared to the normal `enumerate` environment.

However, since `enumerate*` share settings with the `enumerate` environment, how do I go about changing the label for the `enumerate*` environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:** Today the new version with a bug fix is available on `CTAN`.
[enumitem -- Version 3.5.2 -- 2011-09-28](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)

You use the optional argument of the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*.)]
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

To set this behavior global you can use `\setlist`.

**EDIT**

I am using `enumitem.sty 2011/09/05 v3.5.1 Customized lists`. It seems that this version has a bug with `\setlist*`. You can use

```
\setlist[]*{}
```

That works well. But in the documentation is listed:

```
\setlist*[]{}
```

That doesn't work.

Here a small workaround:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\setlist{%
   \@ifstar%
     {\temp@setlist}
     {\temp@@setlist}
}
\newcommand\temp@setlist[1][]{%
  \enit@setlist{#1}\@ne}

\newcommand\temp@@setlist[1][]{%
  \enit@setlist{#1}\z@}

\makeatletter       
%\setlist[enumerate]*{label=(\arabic*.)}
\setlist*[enumerate]{label=(\arabic*.)}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate*}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The problem is the definition of `setlist`

```
\newcommand\setlist[1][]{%
  \@ifstar{\enit@setlist{#1}\@ne}{\enit@setlist{#1}\z@}}
```

`setlist` first check the optional argument before the test `\@ifstar` works.

**EDIT**

Send Bug-report.

EDIT:

The author of `enumitem` will fixed the bug and will upload the new version in one or two weeks.

Comment: Did *you*, or should the *OP* (send a bug-report)?

Comment: @Werner: See my EDIT ;-)

Comment: I used the first approach since I couldn't get any variant of `setlist`, star or no star, to work.

Comment: @gablin: Do you have the same version of `enumitem` You can check it by using the command `\listfiles`.

Comment: @Marco: Yep, got the same version.

Comment: @gablin: And it doesn't work?

Comment: I tried `\setlist[enumerate]*{label=({\roman*})}` but it doesn't take effect. Neither does `\setlist[enumerate]{label=({\roman*})}` (without star).

Comment: @gablin: Without the star you influence the standard environment. Do you try my second example

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `inline`, just create a new list named `enumerate*` of type `enumerate*`. (BTW, I'll fix the bug in `\setlist*`, and a few others in a week or two).